# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'imgUrl')

Tags: mern

**This page will display detailed information about the image when click on it.**

When I click any image I get this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'imgUrl').

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCF-xV3RSSs&t=6993s following this tuturial

I have had no problems using Insomnia. `localhost:8800/api/artworks/find/6494028f22909e921c20d5f4`

```
{
    "dislikes": [],
    "_id": "64940e0f4f775ca36d93e7b6",
    "title": "artwork title 2st user",....}
```

**Artwork.jsx**

```
const Artwork = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  console.log(currentUser); //{_id: '6493e8cd145544b89718c5bb',name: 'test',email: 'test@gmail.com',...}
  const { currentArtwork } = useSelector((state) => state.artwork);
  console.log(currentArtwork); // Null
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const path = useLocation().pathname.split("/")[2];
console.log(`${path}`);
  const [channel, setChannel] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const artworkRes = await axios.get(`/artworks/find/${path}`);
      console.log(artworkRes.data); // no value
      const channelRes = await axios.get(`/users/find/${artworkRes.data.userId}`);
      setChannel(channelRes.data);
      dispatch(fetchSuccess(artworkRes.data));
      console.log(currentArtwork); // no value
      console.log(artworkRes.data); // no value
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err); // no value
    }
  };
  fetchData();
  }, [path, dispatch]);
  
  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        <ArtworkWrapper>
          <ArtworkFrame src={currentArtwork.imgUrl} />
```

**Redux devtool**

[image]

axios.get didnt get any data

```
const artworkRes = await axios.get(`/artworks/find/${path}`);
console.log(artworkRes.data);
```

checked `console.log(axios.get('/artworks/find/6494028f22909e921c20d5f4'));` // promise{...}

**artworkSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  currentArtwork: null,
  loading: false,
  error: false,
};

export const artworkSlice = createSlice({
  name: "artwork",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    fetchStart: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    fetchSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.currentArtwork = action.payload;
    },
    fetchFailure: (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = true;
    },
```